# Synthetic Variables in Bash (was: How to address a variable ceated with indirection)

Tags: bash, indirection

Sorry, that was all too confusing, (my bad)
Let me try to explain again, but with a more simple example:

```
#define a new var and export it to the "env":
export VAR_ONE=thisIsVarOne
# check if it was created:
env | grep VAR_ONE      #this displays: "VAR_ONE=thisIsVarOne"
# use it in a simple echo command:
echo VAR_ONE=$VAR_ONE  #this displays: "VAR_ONE=thisIsVarOne"

# create a new var with the name that contains the value of VAR_ONE ("newvarthisIsVarOne") in its name:
export newvar${VAR_ONE}="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"  
# verify if it has been created:
env | grep newvar  # this displays: "newvarthisIsVarOne=somePrefixthisIsVarOne"
```

#### Now my question:

How do I use that new, syntetic, variable?
Please note that:
`env | grep newvar` shows that there has been created a variable with the name `newvar${VAR_ONE}`

But I can't **address** that new variable, e.g. in an echo command.  I tried:
`echo ${newvar${VAR_ONE}}`
But that gave me `bash: ${newvar${VAR_ONE}}: bad substitution`

#### Constraints:

1. The value of VAR_ONE can change, so I can't use that to address the newly created variable
2. I can't declare a new variable with a static name. For usage, further in the script, I need the keyword `VAR_ONE` as part of the name of the newly created variable.  The name of the variable needs to be something like: `newvar${VAR_ONE}`

Thank you in advance
ChriV

Comment: turn on shell debugging with `set -x` (`set +x` to turn off) and you'll see lines begingging with `+` where all shell pre-processing is complete, so you'll see how the shell interprets `echo newvar${VAR}=${newvar${VAR}}`, for example and then the output from executing that command (the normal output).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `$` to affect a variable in bash:

```bash
var_name=value
var_name1="value with spaces"
var_name2='value with $ or special characters'
```

To get the value of a variable, use a `$` before its name:

```bash
echo "var_name=$var_name"
echo "var_name1=use_braces_to_protect_the variable_name_${var_name1}_"
my_new_var="$var_name2"
```

If your variable contains the name of another variable, you must use an exclamation point before the variable name into braces:

```bash
my_var=spam
the_var_name=my_var
echo "the value is '${!the_var_name}'"
```

So your program will be:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

VAR1=thisIsVar1
#VAR2=thisIsVar2
VAR3=thisIsVar3
VAR_NAMES=($VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3)

echo "VAR_NAMES=" "${VAR_NAMES[@]}"

for VAR_NAME in "${VAR_NAMES[@]}"; do
    echo
    echo "VAR_NAME=$VAR_NAME"

    NEW_VAR_NAME="newvar$VAR_NAME"
    echo "NEW_VAR_NAME=$NEW_VAR_NAME"

    export "${NEW_VAR_NAME}"="somevalue ${VAR_NAME}"
    echo "${NEW_VAR_NAME}=${!NEW_VAR_NAME}"
done
```

## UPDATE

You could also create a hash table (associative array) with new var_name/var_value as key/value:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

VAR1=thisIsVar1
#VAR2=thisIsVar2
VAR3=thisIsVar3
VAR_NAMES=($VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3)

echo "VAR_NAMES=" "${VAR_NAMES[@]}"

declare -A NEW_VAR_NAMES=()

for VAR_NAME in "${VAR_NAMES[@]}"; do
    echo
    echo "VAR_NAME=$VAR_NAME"

    NEW_VAR_NAME="newvar$VAR_NAME"
    echo "NEW_VAR_NAME=$NEW_VAR_NAME"

    export "${NEW_VAR_NAME}"="somevalue ${VAR_NAME}"
    echo "${NEW_VAR_NAME}=${!NEW_VAR_NAME}"

    NEW_VAR_NAMES+=(["${NEW_VAR_NAME}"]=${!NEW_VAR_NAME})
done

echo
echo "${NEW_VAR_NAMES[@]@A}"

for new_var_name in "${!NEW_VAR_NAMES[@]}"; do
    echo "new_var_name is ${new_var_name} and its content is '${NEW_VAR_NAMES[$new_var_name]}'"
done
```

Comment: Hi @Arnaud   
Thank you for your answer  
I do not want to create a new var called NEW_VAR_NAME
I want to create a new VAR that contains the value of another var in its name
e.g.  
```
export newvar${VAR_ONE}="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"    
# check if it was created  
env | grep newvar  # this displays: "newvarthisIsVarOne=somePrefixthisIsVarOne"  
```  
But how do I address this new var in e.g. an "echo" command?

Comment: In my example, the new var names are "`newvar$VAR_NAME`", not "`NEW_VAR_NAME`". "`NEW_VAR_NAME`" is a variable who contains the name of the new var. So the content of new var name is addressable with "`${!NEW_VAR_NAME}`". You cannot use nested braces like this "`${newvar${VAR_NAME}}`"

Comment: So, I successfully created a var called "newvar${VAR_ONE}".  This is my intention.  This variable exists, I can verify with env | grep newvar.  My challenge is: how do I address this new variable e.g. in an "echo" statement?

Comment: `echo $newvarthisIsVar1`. I don't really understand where is the problem

Comment: because $newvarthisIsVar1 assumes you know the content of $VAR_ONE; which I don't

Comment: I have updated my response with the construction of a associative array who contains all variables names and contents

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
export VAR_ONE=thisIsVarOne
```

With `bash 4.3+` you can use a `nameref` (`declare -n`):

```
$ declare -n _var="newvar${VAR_ONE}"            # nameref; define new var name and associate with nameref variable '_var' (can be any valid variable name)
$ _var="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"                   # assign value to nameref

$ echo "${!_var}"                               # show nameref association
newvarthisIsVarOne

$ echo "${_var}"                                # show value
somePrefixthisIsVarOne

$ echo "${newvarthisIsVarOne}"                  # explicitly reference new variable by name
somePrefixthisIsVarOne
```

Comment: thank you,
but I want the **name** of my new var to contain the content of VAR_ONE.  I don't want to create **_var** of any other static name

Comment: So, I successfully created a var called "newvar${VAR_ONE}".    
This is my intention. 
This variable exists, I can verify with env | grep newvar. 
My challenge is: how do I address this new variable e.g. in an "echo" statement? –

Comment: the new variable name *does* contain the content of `VAR_ONE`, see the last `echo` which verifies the new variable (named as desired) exists ; in a separate comment you asked how you can go about referencing the newly created variable ... this shows how you can reference that new variable via the `nameref`, see `echo "${_var}"`

Comment: I'm sorry to take so much of your time.  I'm a +60y old engineer who never had any coding class in his life.  I am trying to understand, but my 2 brain-cells are boiling now.  
I understand that last  echo... but in my case, I don't know the contents of VAR_ONE (being "thisIsVarOne").  In your last echo, you are using that contents.

Comment: My new var has the name `newvar${VAR_ONE}`.  This is confirmed by `env | grep newvar`.  My challenge is how do I use it in an echo command.  I do not know the contents of VAR_ONE, so I cannot use `echo "${newvarthisIsVarOne}" `

Comment: the last echo is merely showing that the variable was created, the next-to-last echo shows use of the nameref ... notice the last two echo commands generate the same ouptut; the nameref functions similiar to a file/symlink; alternatively, think of the nameref as a logical name to a physical variable; if I later run `declare -n _var="newvar${SOME_OTHER_VAR}"` then `_var` will now point to a different/new variable (and it's associated value)

Comment: I've created a 2nd answer that makes use of an associateve array which should be easier (?) to understand

Comment: re: nameref ... imagine you have 3 brothers (Larry, Moe, Curly), the label `brother` would be similar to a nameref; if you establish that `brother=Moe` then you can proceed to reference Moe by the label 'brother' ... brother can you spare a dime, how old are you brother; now suppose you establish that `brother=Larry` then you can proceed to reference Larry by the label 'brother' ... brother can you spare a dime, how old are you brother; clear as mud? :-)

Comment: regarding the one-but-last echo:  that uses a variable called `_var`, that you created here.  For my script, I need to use a variable that is called `newvar${VAR_ONE}` because it is in a loop and it should create things like `newvar${OTHER_VAR}` and `newvar${ANOTHER_VAR}`.   I need this reference to VAR_ONE, OTHER_VAR, and ANOTHER_VAR in the name.  I can't use _var anything static.  PS: thank you for your time to create the "associative array" approach, but I'm afraid that goes way beyond my understanding

Comment: re: 3 different variables ... use 3 namerefs (eg, `_var1`, `_var2`, `_var3`; or `brother1`, `brother2`, `brother3`); the associative array approach allows you to do exactly what you've stated you want to do, but with a slightly different approach to piecing the two parts (`newvar` `${VAR_ONE`) together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149764/discussion-between-chris-v-and-markp-fuso).

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
export VAR_ONE=thisIsVarOne
```

An alternative using an associative array:

```
$ unset      newvar
$ declare -A newvar

$ newvar[${VAR_ONE}]="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"

$ typeset -p newvar
declare -A newvar=([thisIsVarOne]="somePrefixthisIsVarOne" )

$ echo "${newvar[${VAR_ONE}]}"
somePrefixthisIsVarOne
```

---

In a comment OP has stated the need to reference multiple variables, eg, `newvar${VAR_ONE}`, `newvar${OTHER_VAR}` and `newvar${ANOTHER_VAR}`.

This approach with the associative array will work as long as the 3 variables (`VAR_ONE`, `OTHER_VAR` and `ANOTHER_VAR`) have different *values*, otherwise duplicate values will lead to a single array entry being created (with the latest assignment overwriting the previous assignment).

If the 3 variables could have the same *value* then another approach would be to use literals for the associative array's indices, eg:

```
#### instead of:

$ newvar[${VAR_ONE}]="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"

$ typeset -p newvar
declare -A newvar=([thisIsVarOne]="somePrefixthisIsVarOne" )

#### we use:

$ newvar[VAR_ONE]="somePrefix${VAR_ONE}"

$ typeset -p newvar
declare -A newvar=([VAR_ONE]="somePrefixthisIsVarOne" )
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a *shell* variable without using a separate variable (for either the `${!pointer}` syntax or a nameref) the only solution is to use `eval`, for example

```
eval "echo \$newvar$VAR_ONE"
```

-- but this is dangerous it you ever make a mistake, which in practice all people who are humans do.

But **for an *environment* variable** which `export` creates, you can use a child process to do the lookup. In particular `awk` is POSIX and usually present on *most* systems that have `bash`:

```
    awk -v name=newvar$VAR_ONE 'BEGIN{printf "%s",ENVIRON[name]}'
    # or simpler {print ENVIRON[name]} adds newline which may be okay,
    # e.g. if you use this in $(...) or `...` which removes newline
    # or _instead of_ an echo command because echo also adds newline
```

Even simpler, many systems have `printenv` and you can just do `printenv newvar$VAR_ONE` -- which also adds newline.